# Integral yielding auxiliary function for sine/cosine integrals

Tags: integration, complex-integration

The [Abramowitz & Stegun](http://people.math.sfu.ca/%7Ecbm/aands/page_232.htm) section on exponential integrals and related functions includes the following for $\Re(z) \ge 0$:

$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin t}{t+z} \mathrm{d}t = \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-zt}}{t^2+1} \mathrm{d}t.
$$

How can this be shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the well-known and simple to derive
$$\int_0^\infty \exp{(-t y)}\  \sin{\left(b \ y\right)} dy = \frac{b}{t^2+b^2} .$$
Set $b=1.$ Insert into right-hand side of your equation, Interchange $\int.$ Then
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-zt}}{t^2+1} dt= \int_0^\infty dy \sin{y} 
\int_{0}^\infty e^{-t(z+y)}dt = \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin{y}}{y+z} dy$$
where in the last step another elementary integral has been used.